# Attemp with Guard in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, login-attempts

When I try to login the following doesn't work:

```
Auth::guard('pia')->attempt(['email' => $_POST['email'],
                             'password'=>$_POST['password']])
```

If I remove the `guard('pia')` then it is working, but some times it `redirects` to default Laravel `login page` although the user is logged, which I do not want.

Below code for `route`, `auth.php` and `AuthController.php` are provided.

I am using different AuthControllers for different kind of users, also their database tables are separated, like for `pia` table `pia`, for admin table admin etc.

```
routes.php

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'pia'], function() {

        //Login Routes...
        Route::get('login','Pia\AuthController@showLoginForm');
        Route::post('login','Pia\AuthController@login');
        Route::get('logout','Pia\AuthController@logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        Route::get('register', 'Pia\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
        Route::post('register', 'Pia\AuthController@register');
    });

    config/auth.php

    'pia' => [ 
               'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'pia',
             ],
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Pia;

use App\Pia;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Mail;
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $guard = 'pia';
    protected $redirectTo = '/pia/dashboard';
    protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/pia/login';
    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function showLoginForm(){

        if(view()->exists('auth.authenticate')){
            return view('auth.authenticate');
        }
        return view('pia.auth.login');
    }

    public function showRegistrationForm(){

        return view('pia.auth.register');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {   

        if (Auth::guard('pia')->attempt(['email' => $_POST['email'],'password'=>$_POST['password']])) {
            return redirect('/pia/dashboard');
        }else{
             return redirect('/pia/login')->with('warning', 'Problem, try again!'); //
        }
    }
...

}
```